# iOS 1 point view showing up blurred

Tags: ios, uiview

i have a view that is supposed to emulate the separator in a table view.  it is one point in height, calculated by

```
#define kViewHeight 1.0
CGFloat height = kViewHeight / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

but the view comes across with something like an etched look depending on where it is displayed on the screen.  for example, the same view will be a clear one pixel in height, but when the view is scrolled it changes.  a few examples below of the same 3 separator views before and after scrolling.  the views are the same, just had to move to the right to avoid text, so the chevrons are now in the picture.  in the first, the top view is blurry, the bottom two are fine, in the second it's the opposite.

[image: before scrolling...]

[image: after scrolling...]

Comment: This is one of those times where trying on a real device is the best way to figure out the problem. The simulator isn't great with 1px lines, probably due to the screen you're developing on.

Comment: Is this actually happening on live device, or only in the simulator?

Comment: i haven't checked it on a device, will have to do that.  i just found out that if the y value of the frame of one of these is odd, then it will initially show up blurry.  if even, it will show up crisp, but still changes when i scroll...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the position is also integral. That means your CGPoint x and y should be ending with .0
It also means the containing view position and size need to be integral (and anything in the view hierarchy upward)

Google for CGRectIntegral()
It's your friend. Especially when you need pixel alignment.